# HP Pavillion dv5000 inverter input voltage

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hp-pavilion

I have a dv5000. Everything looks fine and working okay, except the backlight doesn't work.
I tried it with [new inverter](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/560/inverterdv5000.jpg/) and a new display, with no success. I measured the voltage input to inverter, and got these results:

- pin 1 and pin 2 are on the same trace  - 10,47 V
- pin 3 - 0,37 V
- pin 4 - 3,27 V
- pin 5 - 0,51 V
- pin 6 and pin 7 are on the same trace - ground 0 V

Can anyone confirm that these are correct or not? I don't want to go any further until someone answer me for these results.

Here is also a magnetic lid switch, but really I'm not sure if this is a sensor for it, but the magnet in front bazel hits this little chip as you can see in [this photo](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/199/dv5000switchboard.jpg/); I also get voltage on it around 3,3 V on input and output!

I found somewhere the answer how to test a switch lid on dv5000, it was written like this:

> if u want to test switch lid on dv5000 just connect A+B on the moment if backlight lights up, just solder this two together, but dont forget to turn off laptop.

I didn't understand what did he mean with "A+B". I want to try it, and turning off laptop is not a problem for me at all!

Comment: posting your quoted source could help solving the problem, as well as being polite to do so.

Comment: So, to confirm, regardless of your old LCD panel, New LCD panel, old inverter or new inverter... and any combination of those 4 things (because you imply you have tried all 4 of those things), you can FAINTLY see that the display is working... aka if you shine a flashlight you can see the Windows desktop... but otherwise nothing you do will illuminate the Cold Cathode Tube in either LCD panel?

Comment: Of course i can see the windows desktop, just backlight doesnt work, i am not sure for that lid switch, does anyone know from where on motherboard is going power to inverter so i can test these, resistors and capacitors, as u can see in my previous post i get some voltage on input (to inverter), but i am not sure if its enough voltage to inverter.

Comment: It seems reasonably to me that the quoted person meant 'permanently connect the two pins of the lid switch into the open position`. That way the backlight will always be on.